# mock up delete function for unit testing in zend framework 2

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, zend-framework2

I have a function like this :

```
<?php

function deleteFromDb(array $where)
{
    $sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
    $delete = $sql->delete();
    $delete->where($where);
    $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($delete);

    return $statement->execute();
}
```

How to mock this function for unit testing in zend framework 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like without Zend Framework - by writing mock yourself, or dynamically generating it by mocking framework(like Mockery).

But i don't see reason why you need to mock this piece of code. There is no if-else operators, no loops, no exception throwing - it's very simple method, so you can be 100% sure that all methods will be called in any possible situation in same way and same count of times. So there is no any profit from mocking this function.

While unit testing this function must be stubbed, so alternative implementation of this function will return constant result at any time. While integration testing you don't need to mock/stub this function in any way - just check real result value.

Comment: If mocking this function is useless so how I assure record deletion from database works ok or not ?

Comment: In integration test? It's simple! After executing this function check that no rows returned by SELECT with same WHERE condition's - they must not be returned. :) You can't fully assure this by mocking. Mocks only purpose is to check if "all functions that must be executed has been executed". Basically you can mock the "Sql" class that used in this code and check if "delete" command is really sent to Database Engine, but is complicates test and also can't guaranty anything really..

Comment: Also most standard way of writing automated integration tests against Database Engines is based on transactions. In arrange part test code creates new transaction and insert some (random or static) data(for sure that needed data will be exists in DB while testing), in act part function under test do some actions against this data, in assert part test code checks if expected actions is done. That's all - function is checked for that it "do what need to do", and real data din'd changed because we didn't committed our test transaction at end of test. :)